# jQuery - How do I make custom event fire only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to control the order in which events are fired. To ensure that my custom event is fired only after another event has finished I am triggering the custom event in the handler of the first event.

```
 $(".HwRadioButton").click(function(event) {    
      //Stuff that needs to happen before custom event
        ...
     //trigger custom event             
        $(".HwRadioButton").trigger("onAnswerChange");
});
```

Custom event binding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".HwRadioButton").bind("onAnswerChange",function(event) {
    //custom event stuff

    });

});
```

The problem is that I have 12 elements that have a class attribute value of ".HwRadioButton". The event, "onAnswerChange" is triggered 12 times. Why is that? Should I even need to select any elements? I just want to define a custom event and explicitly trigger it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code try:

```
 $(".HwRadioButton").click(function(event) {    
      //Stuff that needs to happen before custom event
        ...
     //trigger custom event             
        $(this).trigger("onAnswerChange");
});
```

that will trigger the onAnswerChange on the one element that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) like

```
$('.HwRadioButton').one('click', function() {
  alert('This will be displayed only once.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".HwRadioButton").trigger("onAnswerChange")` triggers `onAnswerChange` for all items selected by that selector. Trigger the event only for `$(this).trigger("onAnswerChange")`.